# Why MQTT need another user when you can see all published topics

Tags: mqtt, iot

why MQTT need to have another user when you can see all published topics of another user ?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71619362/edit) the question to add a lot more context to this question. As it is it really isn't clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQTT users can only see the topics they are allowed to subscribe to. It just so happens that most brokers default settings do not enforce any ACL (Access Control Lists) on what subscriptions users can make so they can in effect see all messages.

If you want to limit what topics a user can subscribe to you should look at the configuration options for your broker to see how it implements ACLs